# SSL proxy for two applications on separate ports on one host name

Tags: web-applications, ssl, nginx, port

We are using Nginx for SSL proxy and have one host name with two applications on two different ports.  What is the best way to set this up in nginx.conf if possible.

Comment: I wanted to add I've tried adding a 2nd listen under the main server but it only seems to pick up the first one and not use the 2nd one at all.

Comment: Solved it.  I just needed to add another listen line for the new port and allow people access to it through IPTables.  I'm a moron.

Answer (score 0):

set up named locations for your apps, and refer to those in the try_files directive:

```
server {
  location @app1 {
    ... (proxy/fcgi/sgci directives depending on what kind of app you're directing to)
  }

  location @app2 {
    ... (proxy/fcgi/sgci directives depending on what kind of app you're directing to)
  }

  location /app-path1/ {try_files @app1;}
  location /app-path2/ {try_files @app2;}
}
```

Comment: Ok i'm trying this but I think I'm missing part of it under location can that be a proxy_pass?  And where exactly do I need to point to the different ports?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way for us to do this since it is all internal was to just add another listen line for the other port on the same host.

The reason it wasn't working was because I had IPTABLES locked down and forgot.

Solved.  Sorry for the trouble.